# MyGeneration Template Creation Tutorials

Tags: code-generation, mygeneration

Just wondering if anyone has some good resources for learning how to create new templates with MyGeneration?

I've only found a couple of very basic introductions so far, and the majority of the rest of the documentation appears to be about generating code with the existing templates.

I'm looking to write some templates of my own to better fit in with how I do things, so would ideally like something that walks through how this should best be approached, rather than having to try and dig through the existing templates and figure out how they work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following resources:

- [Code Project Overview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/GriffinMyGen.aspx)
- [Introduction by MyGenerationSoftware Team](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Article/?guid=485028ae-85bc-4c5f-acb4-27bd4db16363)
- [MyGenerationSoftware TemplateLibrary Articles](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Articles/)